# How do I parse dynamic value to attribute in kv file?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51987320/pass-variables-from-py-to-kv-file) topic however the solution didn't work for me.

py file:

```
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

class ResultsListScreen(Screen):
    image = StringProperty('/icon.png')
```

kv file:

```
#:import os_ubuntu os

<Row@BoxLayout>:
    id: row
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    value: ''
    image: ''
    Label:
        id: rv
        text: root.value
    Image:
        source: os_ubuntu.getcwd()+'%s' %(root.image)
```

How do I make it work in my case ? The image file is located in the same directory as the py & kv files.

Answer (score 0):

In your 'kv' file, you would normally do something like:

```
source: root.image
```

But that would depend on the `image` `StringProperty` being defined in the `Row` class. So, you can either define the `image` in the `Row` class, or you can get a reference to the `ResultsListScreen`, and use that to access `image`. Without a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I cannot give a specific answer about accessing `ResultsListScreen`.