# how to pass return value of function to .kv file and set it as text of label

Tags: python, variables, pycharm, kivy, parameter-passing

This is my .py file:

```
def heap_sort(self,text):           ##Function to sort the heap
        size=int(text)
        num=copy.deepcopy(myclass.randomlist)

        for i in range(((size//2)-1),-1,-1):        ##build heap
            self.heapify(num,size,i)

        for i in range(size-1):         ##sorting the array
            num[size-1],num[0]=num[0],num[size-1]  ##swap root and last element
            size=size-1                           ## reducing size of heap by 1
            self.heapify(num, size, 0)         ## heapify the heap to maintain max heap property
        print("Array sorted by heap sort")
        print(num)
        arr=' '.join(map(str, num))
        return arr
```

This function above returns sorted array as a string i want to pass this "arr" string to .kv file and set it as text of label

This is my .kv file below:

```
Label:
        id:l3
        text:root.heap_sort(t1.text)
        font_size:26
        size_hint:(.5,.5)
        pos:(10,340)
```

But it give me error:

```
  File "C:\Users\ashee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 690, in _apply_rule
     value, bound = create_handler(
   File "C:\Users\ashee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 252, in create_handler
     raise BuilderException(rule.ctx, rule.line,
```

Help me how to resolve it Thanks..

Comment: Does this help? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51987320/pass-variables-from-py-to-kv-file)

Comment: no its not helpfull